# Process data in batches to prevent Out Of Memory exceptions

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my TensorFlow network, I calculate

```
Y = (X * C) * R,
```

where:

- `X` is `(n, d)`,
- `C` is `(d, L)`,
- `X * C` is `(n, L)`,
- `R` is `(L, d)`,
- `Y` is `(n, d)`.

The problem is that `n ≈ 1e6` and `L ≈ 1e5`, and so `X * C` does not fit into memory, but `d = 4`, so `Y` would fit into memory. I don't really need to store `X * C`.

`Y = (X * C) * R` could be calculated in batches, i.e.,

```
Y[0:1000,    :] = (X[0:1000,    :] * C) * R
Y[1000:2000, :] = (X[1000:2000, :] * C) * R
...
```

Is there a neat way to tell TensorFlow to do this? Or what is a standard procedure here?

Comment: Does computing Y = X * (R^T * C^T)^T work?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work but has the undesired side effect of creating a variable!

Any ideas on how to improve on this?

```
n, d, L = 40, 2, 3
num_batches = 10
rows_per_batch = n // num_batches

X = tf.constant(np.arange(n*d, dtype=np.float32).reshape(n, d))
C = tf.constant(np.arange(d*L, dtype=np.float32).reshape(d, L))
R = tf.constant(np.arange(L*d, dtype=np.float32).reshape(L, d))

Y = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(X, C), R)

yvar = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0, shape=Y.get_shape(), dtype=tf.float32))

def condition(current_batch):
    return current_batch < num_batches

def body(current_batch):
    current_rows_to_update = tf.range(rows_per_batch * current_batch,
                                      rows_per_batch * (current_batch + 1))
    xbatch = tf.gather(X, current_rows_to_update)
    ybatch = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(xbatch, C), R, name='matmul_da')

    yvar_update = tf.scatter_update(yvar, current_rows_to_update, ybatch)

    with tf.control_dependencies([yvar_update]):
        return current_batch + 1

loop = tf.while_loop(condition, body, loop_vars=[0])
with tf.control_dependencies([loop]):
    ybatched = tf.identity(yvar)
```